# Count of unique value in column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a dataframe and I am looking at one column within the dataframe called names

```
array(['Katherine', 'Robert', 'Anne', nan, 'Susan', 'other'], dtype=object)
```

I am trying to make a call to tell me how many times each of these unique names shows up in the column, for example if there are 223 instances of Katherine etc. 
How do i do this? i know value_counts just shows 1 for each of these because they are the separate unique values

Comment: `value_counts` is what you want.  If there is more than one occurrence it should show them.  If you think it's not doing that, please show a complete example demonstrating the problem.  Note that you need to use `.value_counts()` on your actual column, not on the list of unique values.

Comment: @BrenBarn there must be a dupe for this question, it has been asked so many times, still searching

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [pandas.Series.value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(['Katherine', 'Robert', 'Anne', np.nan, 'Susan', 'other'])

s.value_counts()

Katherine    1
Robert       1
other        1
Anne         1
Susan        1
dtype: int64
```

The data you provided only has one of each name - so here is an example with multiple 'Katherine' entries:

```
s = pd.Series(['Katherine','Katherine','Katherine','Katherine', 'Robert', 'Anne', np.nan, 'Susan', 'other'])

s.value_counts()

Katherine    4
Robert       1
other        1
Anne         1
Susan        1
dtype: int64
```

When applied to your **Dataframe** you will call this as follows:

```
df['names'].value_counts()
```

Comment: dropna = "False"

Answer (score -1):

You could use group by to achieve that:

```
df[['col1']].groupby(['col1']).agg(['count'])
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. `df[['col1']]` will return a one column DataFrame. If you group the DataFrame on that column `agg` will not be able to find any other columns to aggregate. You can use `.size()` instead of `agg('count')`  but I'd go with `value_counts`.